# Obtener días - POO Javascript

Tags: javascript, poo, date

Alguien sabría explicarme u orientarme cómo puedo hacer para que pueda mostrar en pantalla los **primeros domingos de cada mes** del año pasado como parámetro? En este caso 2018.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Objeto(anio) {
 this.anio=anio;
 this.calculaFechas=function() {
  var hoy=new Date();
  domingo=hoy.getDay(0);
  mes=hoy.getMonth()+1;
  anio=hoy.getFullYear();
 }
 this.imprimeFechas=function() {
  /*document.write("Primeros domingos de cada mes del año 2018: " +domingo+ "-" +mes+ "-" +anio);*/

 }
}

var objeto1=new Objeto(2018);
objeto1.imprimeFechas();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no consigues hacer? ¿Mostrar la información u obtener los primeros domingos del mes?

Answer (score 5):

Una posible forma de hacerlo sería así:

```js
    
    function Objeto(anio) {
     this.anio=anio;
     this.imprimeFechas=function() {
      document.write("Primeros domingos de cada mes del año 2018:");
    
      for(m = 0; m < 12; m++){
       var date = new Date(this.anio, m, 1);
       while (date.getDay() != 0) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
       }
       document.write("<li>"+date+"</li>");
      }
     }
    }
    
    var objeto1=new Objeto(2018);
    objeto1.imprimeFechas();
```

Recorres cada uno de los meses y buscas el primer día 0 (domingo).

Comment: +1 por la idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con este método, en el que calculo el primer domingo y posteriormente voy iterando por los siguientes sumando 7 días a la fecha:

```js
function Objeto(anio) {
  this.anio = anio;
  this.imprimeFechas = function() {
    /* Calculamos el primer domingo del año */
    let fecha = new Date(this.anio + '-01-01');
    if (fecha.getDay() > 0) {
      fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 7 - fecha.getDay());
    }

    /* Iteramos domingo a domingo dentro del mismo año */
    let mes = false;
    while (fecha.getFullYear() == this.anio) {
      /* Si hemos cambiado de mes mostramos el primer domingo */
      if (mes !== fecha.getMonth()) {
        console.log(fecha);
        mes = fecha.getMonth();
      }
      fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 7);
    }
  }
}
var objeto1=new Objeto(2018);
objeto1.imprimeFechas();
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera (*es solo la función en el bloque de script*)

```js
function firstSundays(year) {
  let domingos = [];
  // Iniciamos en el mes 0 = Enero
  for (mes = 0; mes < 12; mes++) {
    // La semana tiene 7 dias por lo tanto el 1er domingo debe estar en uno de esos dias
    for (dia = 1; dia < 8; dia++) {
      let fecha = new Date(year, mes, dia);
      if (fecha.getDay() == 0) {
        // Puedes imprimirlo
        console.log(fecha);
        // OPCIONAL, lo guardas en un array
        domingos.push(fecha);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // OPCIONAL si lo guardas en un array los 1ros domingos y quieres imprimir el mes
  let meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]

  for (i = 0; i < domingos.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${domingos[i].getDate()}-${meses[domingos[i].getMonth()]}-${year}`);
  }
}

// Llamar función.
firstSundays(2018);
```

Puedes cambiar los **console.log** por **document.write** *(recuerda que la función write sobreescribe todo tu documento html)*.

Comment: Debes declarar las variables en el for: `for (var mes = ...` o `for (let mes =...`